# CPP Socket Programming

Tags: c++, sockets

I am new to `C++`. I want to study socket programming. firstly like a simple chat with a client/server. I don't know where to start and how to start.
Is there any good guides and example programs for beginners. I searched a lot of things in net and its too difficult to understand.

Comment: "I searched a lot of things in net and its too difficult to understand.". Did you work through the examples you've found? If so, take one thing about them that you're having difficulty understanding and ask about that as a specific question. This question is overly broad for [this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about/) and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: You cannot simply not buy a UNIX Network Programming book by Richard Stevens.

Answer (score 3):

[Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) isn't that hard to learn. Take time to read its [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) and [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).

Answer (score 2):

i found http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ great easy understand and get into programming mode faster